# How to get the last key/value of rowpefix filter in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, scanf, hortonworks-data-platform

My hbase table rowkey are in following format:

```
vin1ts1

vin1ts2

vin1ts3

vin2ts1

vin2ts2

vin2ts3

vin2ts4

etc....
```

I would like to get the last available key of each ROWPREFIX ,

where ROWPREFIX ={VIN1, VIN2, VIN3,...}

Example: for RowPrefix= VIN1, It should return "Rowkey=vin1ts3"   & its values.

---

I am trying to use the reverse scan feature as below:

```
`Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCaching(1)
FilterList allFilters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
allFilters.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(prefixFilterValue)));
scan.setFilter(allFilters);
scan.setReversed(true); //Read the latest available key and value
scan.setMaxResultSize(1);
ResultScanner scanner = tblConn.getScanner(scan);
Result result = scanner.next();
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Latest Key " + Bytes.toString(result.getRow()));
scanner.close(); 
-----------`
```

Above code works but takes around ~40 second to retrieve the target rowkey.

Is there any better approach to get the same since 40 second is not sufficing our business condition ?

Or do I need to set any scan property to reduce the scanner time ?

Any pointers would be appreciated..

CLUSER INFO:
HDP:
HDP-2.5.5.0

hbase -version:
Version 1.1.2.2.5.5.0-157, r002c801447187c620c26ffc130ff17a9b0a62ac1, Fri Apr 21 01:13:10 UTC 2017

Thank you!

Comment: You should review the design of your HBase table. The cells have already a timestamp that you can use to get the last value (default behavior) so don’t put a timestamp in the rowkey. And HBASE scanners should be avoided unless you pass a rowkey prefix.

Comment: I can not use default Timestamp behavior because of application constraints,        Anyways I am using  Rowprefix filter for my scan request as you can see. surprisingly, reverse=true is not performing well as per expectation.

Comment: I can not use default Timestamp behavior because of application constraints,        Anyways I am using  Rowprefix filter for my scan request as you can see. surprisingly, reverse=true is not performing well as per expectation.                                                                                                           It performs well incase table contains the data in few thousands but it start taking time when data count goes into millions[Pls note, for one rowprefix, data count will always be less than thousands]

Comment: sorry, I answered too quickly. yes it should be fast (less than 1 sec) even with a table containing millions of rows

Comment: Have you checked if your table is correctly distributed across regions servers?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing scan.setCaching(1) ? This does a round-trip to your server for every single record as you are iterating through them. I don't know how many results you expect to get per each call, but if it's a lot, and you want the last one, then this will reduce the performance by a lot.

Comment: scan.setCaching(1)  --> because I want to read just one record from result which will start scanning table in reverse order [reverse=true]]

Comment: @Harold I guess, Its well distributed into 22 regions , Incase this is an issue then it should also impact the prefix filter [not performed in reverse order] , am I right ? Or How should I check the answer for well distribution of table ?

Comment: @Revan, yes you would observe same degraded performance with a normal prefix filter. Did you check the same reverse filter with hbase shell?

Comment: @Harold Actually , Yes. But query is not retrieving the target data even its present.          scan 'DB:TBL', {LIMIT => 1, REVERSED => TRUE, ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'vin1'},    I read somewhere on stackoverflow that hbase shell doesn't support the reverse scan query with some specific versions, is it true ? or am I missing anything ?

Comment: Did you try getting the row keys only? `FilterList filters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL,
            new FirstKeyOnlyFilter(),
            new KeyOnlyFilter());`